# Looking up if a value is present in a collection (small collection, several checks per second)

Tags: java, collections, lookup

I need to implement a very efficient method of checking if a certain key (long value) is present in a small collection of items (less than 100, usually around 10) in java.

This check must be as efficient as possible, as it is going to be made several times per second (more than 1000, I'm treating an Multicast feed and i want to discard messages that i don't need to treat).

The items that need to be checked is going to vary almost nothing during the application life cycle, and it can be expensive in terms of performance.

Thanks

> Thanks for all the prompt replies. My concern is that my long keys might be very concentrated in a small range of the long, and I'm worried about it. If you guys think that it wont be an issue, I'll give it a try.

Comment: is `Collection's` `contains()` method not efficient enough?

Comment: If all the items are unique, Set.Contains is O(1) and should be very fast.

Comment: Re your edited concern - don't worry. See my (edited) answer for more

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`HashSet<Long>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) - it will take nanoseconds (literally) for `contains()` to return.

Code something like this:

```
private static Set<Long> keys = new HashSet<Long>();
// populate keys

if (keys.contains(requestKey)) { // this call is super fast!
    // ignore request
}
```

#### Edited:

Don't worry about your longs being "close" together. The `hashCode()` of `Long` is sufficiently "scattered" that for all practical purposes no pattern to it - that is, Longs that are "close" do not have hash codes that are "close".

Comment: To confirm: on a good desktop pc, calls to contains on a set containing 100 items take around than 1,000 ns on average, so 1,000 calls would take aobut 1 ms.

Answer (score 0):

If efficiency takes precedence over versatility, you might consider using Trove's [`TLongHashSet`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sf/trove4j/trove4j/2.0.2/trove4j-2.0.2-javadoc.jar!/gnu/trove/TLongHashSet.html):

> An open addressed set implementation for long primitives.

This would give you O(1) and avoid autoboxing entirely. But this might be an extreme choice for such a small collection.